# Unresolved reference: R in all of my Fragments Direction classes

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I have several fragments in the app, and some of them transfer data to each other using safe args. I've tried cleaning and rebuilding the project, but the error persists.

The error comes from the `import R` in the Fragment_nameFragmentDirections classes that are generated when it's building a project

For example:

```
package project.folder1.tabletracker

import R
import androidx.navigation.ActionOnlyNavDirections
import androidx.navigation.NavDirections

public class AddTableFragmentDirections private constructor() {
  public companion object {
    public fun actionAddTableFragmentToHomeFragment(): NavDirections =
        ActionOnlyNavDirections(R.id.action_addTableFragment_to_homeFragment)
  }
}
```

Since it's the problem in a build folder, I think the problem have something to do with my build.gradle but I do not know what exactly.
This is my build.gradle project level:

```
    plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.3.1' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.3.1' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.7.20' apply false
    id 'androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin' version '2.4.1' apply false
}
```

And this is my build.gradle app level:

```
    plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
    id 'androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin'
}



android {
    namespace 'project.folder1.tabletracker'
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "project.folder1.tabletracker"
        minSdk 23
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.8.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
    kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.5.1"
    def room_version = "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.5.1"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:2.5.1"
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.6.0'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.6.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.3.1'
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.4.1"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.4.1"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error might be due to missing import in your Fragment.
Make sure that your Fragment importing the correct R class. The import statement should look like this:

```
import project.folder1.tabletracker.R
```

**Note : the package name in the import statement should match the namespace value in your build.gradle file.**

Comment: I'm sorry for not being specific in my question, but the error comes from the import R in the FragmentNameFragmentDirections class that are generated when you are building a project.